# mysql match with regex exact words?

Tags: mysql, regex, match

I want to match 2 exact words like

```
select col from mytable where col like '%one%two%'
```

but using

```
select col from mytable where col RLIKE '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]][[:<:]]two[[:>:]]'
```

it didnt' work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try full text search? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. You need `.*` between `one` and `two` as these are 2 different words. `.*` will match 0 or more length text between these 2 words.

Use this query:

```
select col from mytable where col RLIKE '[[:<:]]one[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]two[[:>:]]'
```